# How to assign a number to an image in html?

Tags: javascript, html, image

To be clear, how can I associate an image with a number? I am trying to make a "how many fingers game" using javascript. I am going to use images for answers. So there will be images for each number.(For example an image showing one finger for the answer one.) When one of the images is clicked, the program should check if the random number(0,1,2,3,4 or 5) is equal to the number of fingers in image.

I guess img tag can't get a value attribute. I tried giving a value to an each image and setting an if statement according to that, but it didn't work.

It gives always wrong as an output. jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4g0weo75/

```
<!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Java script</title>

      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
      <style type="text/css">
      .break{
        clear:both;
      }
      #answer{
        float:left;
      }
      #myButton{
        float:left;
      }
      .fingers{
        float:left;
        display:block;
        padding-right:50px;
      }
      .fingers img{
        border:1px solid black;
        border-radius:20px;
      }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <img width="100px" height="auto" src="http://i62.tinypic.com/2rr55xv_th.jpg" />
      <p>How many fingers am I holding up?</p>
      <div class="break"></div>

      <p class="fingers"><img id="zero" src="http://i61.tinypic.com/140jfnp_th.png" value="0" /></p>
      <p class="fingers"><img id="one" src="http://i61.tinypic.com/6tfgpv_th.png" value="1" /></p>
      <p class="fingers"><img id="two" src="http://i62.tinypic.com/2w685ya_th.png" value="2" /></a></p>
      <p class="fingers"><img id="three" src="http://i58.tinypic.com/hsrksj_th.png" value="3" /></a></p>
      <p class="fingers"><img id="four" src="http://i57.tinypic.com/igdfrc_th.png" value="4" /></a></p>
      <p class="fingers"><img id="five" src="http://i60.tinypic.com/2useki1_th.png" value="5" /></a></p>

      <script type="text/javascript">

        document.getElementById("zero").onclick=function(){

          var x=Math.random(x);
          x=6*x;
          x=Math.floor(x);

          if (x==document.getElementById("zero").value){
            alert ("You got it!!");
          }else {
            alert ("You're wrong. The number was: "+x);
          }

        }

        document.getElementById("one").onclick=function(){

          var x=Math.random(x);
          x=6*x;
          x=Math.floor(x);

          if (x==document.getElementById("one").value){
            alert ("You got it!!");
          }else {
            alert ("You're wrong. The number was: "+x);
          }

        }

        document.getElementById("two").onclick=function(){

          var x=Math.random(x);
          x=6*x;
          x=Math.floor(x);

          if (x==document.getElementById("two").value){
            alert ("You got it!!");
          }else {
            alert ("You're wrong. The number was: "+x);
          }

        }

        document.getElementById("three").onclick=function(){

          var x=Math.random(x);
          x=6*x;
          x=Math.floor(x);

          if (x==document.getElementById("three").value){
            alert ("You got it!!");
          }else {
            alert ("You're wrong. The number was: "+x);
          }

        }

        document.getElementById("four").onclick=function(){

          var x=Math.random(x);
          x=6*x;
          x=Math.floor(x);

          if (x==document.getElementById("four").value){
            alert ("You got it!!");
          }else {
            alert ("You're wrong. The number was: "+x);
          }

        }

        document.getElementById("five").onclick=function(){

          var x=Math.random(x);
          x=6*x;
          x=Math.floor(x);


          if (x==document.getElementById("five").value){
            alert ("You got it!!");
          }else {
            alert ("You're wrong. The number was: "+x);
          }
        }

      </script>
    </body>
  </html>
  <!-- end snippet -->
```

Comment: Just use data attributes. `data-value` instead of `value`. Then retreive it using `document.getElementById("one").getAttribute('data-value')`

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I want and it worked pretty well!! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to use the [data attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) available from html5, you could change the code to:

```
    <p class="fingers"><img id="zero" src="http://i61.tinypic.com/140jfnp_th.png" data-value="0" /></p>
    <p class="fingers"><img id="one" src="http://i61.tinypic.com/6tfgpv_th.png" data-value="1" /></p>
    <p class="fingers"><img id="two" src="http://i62.tinypic.com/2w685ya_th.png" data-value="2" /></a></p>
    <p class="fingers"><img id="three" src="http://i58.tinypic.com/hsrksj_th.png" data-value="3" /></a></p>
    <p class="fingers"><img id="four" src="http://i57.tinypic.com/igdfrc_th.png" data-value="4" /></a></p>
    <p class="fingers"><img id="five" src="http://i60.tinypic.com/2useki1_th.png" data-value="5" /></a></p>
```

Then you could use the following line:

```
document.getElementById("zero").getAttribute('data-value')
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer since data-* attributes are used to store custom data private to the page or application.

Answer (score 0):

In this case `value` is an attribute of tag so instead `document.getElementById("two").value` use `document.getElementById("two").getAttribute('value')`.
You can use `document.getElementById('some_form_element_id').value` with form elements - image is not a form element.